# MySQL / PHP - Tables dont get Informations from my Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have a Form in the frontend where Users can input stuff.

When i input my Informations in the Form and submit, the database only collect 2 out of 5 Informations. 1 correct one, and a wrong one. I've been trying to find a solution for 6 hours, but i failed.

When i use  " if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { "

in front off " if($current_user->user_login == ""){  " the Site just refresh and no informations goes into the DB.

When i dont use it, 2 new columns will be created. One when i enter the Site, and one after i submit the Form. (Only with 2 Informations in it.)

"username" is correct. 
"plaetze" is wrong (shows 0 all the time)
 The other 3 do not even get an information.

[Picture of the informations in the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVj45.png)

My PHP / SQL Code:

```
$host="localhost"; 
 $username="xxx"; 
 $password="xxx";
 $db_name="xxxx"; 
 $tbl_name="xxxx"; 

 $link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    die("Es gab einen Fehler beim Verbinden zur Datenbank");
}


if($current_user->user_login == ""){
  echo "Bitte logge dich ein damit du ein Angebot abschicken kannst";

} else {
$username = $current_user->user_login;
$plaetze = $_POST['anzahlplaetzeselect'];
$gender = $_POST['genderselect'];
$kosten = $_POST['unchoice'];
$bemerkung = $_POST['apkostenfreibemerkung'];

$query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, plaetze, genderchoice, kosten, kostenbemerkung) VALUES('$username', '$plaetze', '$gender', '$kosten', '$bemerkung')";
  if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    echo "<p> Dein Angebot wurde erfolgreich erstellt </p>";
  } else {
    echo "<p>Fail!</p>";
  }
}
 ?>
```

My Form:

```
<button type="button" id="ubernachtungenAKtivieren" class="btn">Eine Übernachtung anbieten</button>

<div id="ubernachtungsformdiv">

<form type="post" name="ubernachtungform" id="ubernachtungsform">

  <div class="form-group">
    <?php
          if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
          return;
     ?>
     <p> <b>Dein Benutzername:</b> <a href="<?php echo 'https://examplexxxx' . bp_core_get_username( get_current_user_id() ) . '/profile/' ?> "> <?php echo $current_user->user_login ?> </a></p>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="anzahlplätze">Wie viele Übernachtungsplätze bietest du an?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="anzahlplaetzeselect" id="anzahlplaetzeselect">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="10">10</option>
   </select>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="genderselect">Ich nehme nur...</label>
<select class="form-control" name="genderselect" id="genderselect">
  <option value="maenner">Männer auf</option>
  <option value="frauen">Frauen auf</option>
  <option value="egal">Egal ob Mann oder Frau auf</option>
</select>

</div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Wie viel kostet eine Übernachtung bei Dir?</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="radio" id="apkostenfrei" name="unchoice" value="apkostenfrei" checked="checked" >
      <label for="apkostenfrei">Kostenfrei</label></br>

      <div id="bemerkungsfeld" style="display: none">
        <label for="apkostenfreibemerkung">Bemerkung:</label>
        <input type="text" id="apkostenfreibemerkung" name="apkostenfreibemerkung" placeholder="Gegen ein Gastgeschenk/6er Bier o.Ä"> </br>
      </div>

      <input type="radio" id="kostenpflichtig" name="unchoice" value="apkosten">
      <label for="kostenpflichtig">Kostenpflichtig</label></br>
    </div>

    <div id="preisfeld" style="display: none">
      <label for="preis">Ich nehme</label>
      <input type="number" id="preis" name="preis" placeholder="15">
      <label for="preis">Euro</label>
    </div>

<input type="submit" name="angebotabschicken" class="btn" id="UNsend" value="Dieses Angebot für die Veranstaltung <?php wp_title() ?> erstellen!" >

</div>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<form type="post"` should be `<form method="post"` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form for a list of the correct attributes). Since you didn't set the "method" attribute, the form is submitting using GET (which is the default) instead of POST. This is why checking that it's a POST is failing, and why your $_POST variables are blank when you don't make that check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
<form type="post" name="ubernachtungform" id="ubernachtungsform">
```

It should be

```
<form method="post" name="ubernachtungform" id="ubernachtungsform">
```

As there is no correct option specified, the data will never be sent through a POST request. It will be sent by default using a GET request. Change that and you are good to go